# How to convert mutable.Map to mutable.HashMap in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, collections, mutable

I'm extending Sparks `AccumulableParam[mutable.HashMap[Int,Long], Int]` with Scala, for some experiments. Part of this, is to define the method `def addInPlace(t1: mutable.HashMap[Int,Long], t2: mutable.HashMap[Int,Long]): mutable.HashMap[Int,Long]`.

**What I want to do:**

```
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

def addInPlace(t1: mutable.HashMap[Int,Long], t2: mutable.HashMap[Int,Long]): 
 mutable.HashMap[Int,Long] = {
   t1 ++ t2.map { case (s, c) => (s, c + t1.getOrElse(s, 0L)) }
}
```

**I get the error:**

> Expression of type mutable.Map[Int, Long] doesn't conform to selected type mutable.HashMap[Int, Long]

In this case the `++` operator returns Map instead of HashMap, even though both terms `t1` and `t2.map {...}` are of type `HashMap[int, Long]`.

**So my question is**, how to make `++` return a HashMap instead, or how to convert the resulting `Map` to a `HashMap`.

Comment: Why do you need to work with the concrete `HashMap`? `Map` under the covers will use `HashMap`.

Comment: What he said ^^^. Just declare everything as `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly way to do it is to use `asInstanceOf[mutable.HashMap[Int, Long]]` on the result map:

```
def addInPlace(t1: mutable.HashMap[Int,Long], t2: mutable.HashMap[Int,Long]): mutable.HashMap[Int,Long] = {
  val result = t1 ++ t2.map { case (s, c) => (s, c + t1.getOrElse(s, 0L)) }
  result.asInstanceOf[mutable.HashMap[Int, Long]]
}
```